# Is it true that $ \sqrt{z^2-1} = i \sqrt{1-z^2} $?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have seen a lot of times in books or on the internet that$ \sqrt{z^2-1} = i \sqrt{1-z^2} $   and I don't understand why that is correct . In general it is not true that $ \sqrt{-z}=i  \sqrt {z}$ and I think that we use that to show the above.

I think if $(1-z^2)$ has argument in $(-π,0]$, then we have that $ \sqrt{-z}=i  \sqrt {z}$ but it's not always like that, for example if $z=-2+i$ then $ z^2=4-4i-1$ so $ 1-z^2=-2+4i $ and that one has not the argument that we want.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This needs a definition of a single-valued function $\sqrt{z}$ when $z$ is complex to make any kind of *sense*, before you start discussing *truth*

Comment: yes , if $ z= r*e^{ιθ}$  where r>0 and θ  is the argument of z  we define $\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}*e^{iθ/2} $

Comment: Could you please explain why the answer to your earlier question, [Is it true that $\sqrt{-z} = i\sqrt{z}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836822), doesn't address this as well?

Comment: Because i just want to know if that is always correct for $ 1-z^2 $ , if that makes problem to the site i will delete the other one if i can.

Comment: I edited until I lost track of what was even being claimed. Feel free to adjust further.

Comment: What is true is that the *pair* of complex numbers $\pm\sqrt{z}$ is the same pair of numbers as $\pm i\sqrt{-z}$

Comment: @TheCount it's alright , i fixed it and thanks for your edit!

Comment: @MPW how can we prove that?

Comment: @EvansS. thanks! you are the best! nice clean-up. it's definitely a little more readable now.

Comment: @EvansS. : If $z=0$, all of them are just $0$. Otherwise, every nonzero complex number has precisely two distinct square roots, and note that $(\pm iw)^2 = (\pm 1)^2i^2w^2=-w^2$, and $(\pm w)^2=(\pm 1)^2w^2=w^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the definition of the square root. Every complex number has 2 square roots (except 0), and we agree that if the number is real and positive, the sign $ \sqrt ?$ means to take the positive root. But when we're dealing with a general complex number z, we don't have one good way to define which of the roots will be $\sqrt z$. So for a general $z$, the eqation you wrote isn't well defined.

However, it is true that $\frac{\sqrt {1-z^2}}{\sqrt {z^2-1}}$ will always be $i$ or $-i$, no matter which root you choose for those numbers.

Comment: how can we show that $ \frac{\sqrt {1-z^2}}{\sqrt {z^2-1}} = i $ or $ - i$ ?

Comment: If you raise the experssion by the power of 2 you get -1, and therefore it can only be $\pm i$